# no root file system defined error in ubuntu 13.10 installation

Tags: installation, wubi

I have installed ubuntu 13.10 along with windows 7 without creating any new partition. I am using a bootable pendrive to do so and the installation completes succesfully in the same drive in which windows is installed. But when the pc restarts to complete the installation this error shows up !! This same thing is successfully completed in another pc but in my pc it is showing an error. Pls help as i dont want to create a new partition and dont want to run it as a live cd.

Comment: How can you install Ubuntu along with Windows without creating a new partition?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, digest this fact -- ubuntu works on an ext4 partition while, on the otherhand, Windows runs on an NTFS partition. If you decide to run Ubuntu and Windows on same partition, you might want to consider using Wubi.exe(Windows Ubuntu Installer).
[This installs Ubuntu and Windows on the same partition, but i would suggest you have two different partitions for the sake of performance. I believe that the system becomes slow in course of time due to fragmentation -- SUMMARY: use different partitions for Ubuntu and Windows].

Otherwise, if you decide to remove Windows (ofcourse after backing up all the important data) and shift to Ubuntu, while installing Ubuntu, go for the option "Other", and go for creating a new partition table, then define the root for your file system, and then install ubuntu.